# Flutter : Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'

Tags: ios, flutter

**Here is the error that i faced while running the code in flutter**

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'
/Users/rabinacharya/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3/ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.s
wift:259:43


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'
/Users/rabinacharya/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3/ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.s
wift:293:43


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Build input files cannot be found:
'/Users/rabinacharya/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/shared_preferences_foundation-2.2.2/darwin/Classes/messag
es.g.swift',
'/Users/rabinacharya/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/shared_preferences_foundation-2.2.2/darwin/Classes/Shared
PreferencesPlugin.swift'


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Build input files cannot be found:
'/Users/rabinacharya/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/path_provider_foundation-2.2.3/darwin/Classes/messages.g.
swift',
'/Users/rabinacharya/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/path_provider_foundation-2.2.3/darwin/Classes/PathProvide
rPlugin.swift'


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

**How to reproduce it ?**

Delete the current iOS
Run the command below:
`flutter create -i swift .`

This will generate the errors mentioned above

Comment: No not yet I haven't got the solution yet

Comment: Does this issue happen when you use a device as well or only with emulators?

Comment: This happens with the emulators but I haven't tested it on real device,I don't have one :) @FilipePilettiPlucenio